# Camera shake produces ripple-like effect

Tags: video, digital-recording

I'm using a Kodak Zi8 at the moment, but I've noticed this effect on other cameras. When a camera is moving it occasionally produces fun house mirror-style effects. It makes things appear to stretch and shrink. Is this a software issue or a problem with cheap components? Are there any cameras that don't produce this effect?

See example video:

[Kodak Zi8 shake issue](http://vimeo.com/44503828) from [Reed Law](http://vimeo.com/reedlaw) on [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This "effect" is called [Rolling Shutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter). It is common in most CMOS camera sensors because they don't capture an instantaneous image, instead they do it progressively over a period of time. CCD sensors do not have this problem as they do have instantaneous capture.

Answer (score 4):

It is down to the raster/line speed of the CMOS array in your camera - it does not expose the whole thing at once, it scans from left to right and downwards. For even more amusement google for iPhone propellor videos, such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAbj3nL_i58), or in fact any video of oscillating or moving objects.

The solution is to get equipment with slightly more upmarket sensor arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Look in your video editing software for "Rolling Shutter" correction.  That will help, but probably not completely eliminate, the problem.